# Problem at the Table of Contents in Lyx

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

I use Lyx 2.1, document class : report.
At the table of Contents, no spacing between "a few" under sections.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps someone can guess the correct cause from the screenshot alone, but I for one cannot, so it would really help if you added a minimal example: First create the smallest LyX-document you can that demonstrates the problem. Then either 1) open that .lyx file in a text editor, copy the entire file, and paste it into your question, or 2) export to a LaTeX file (File -> Export -> LaTeX (pdflatex)), open this file and copy-paste all the text into your post. See also http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I'd like to note one thing: *Minimal* is a keyword when creating example, we really don't need to see your entire document. That's why I wrote 'create the *smallest* document that demonstrates the problem.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason you have added some vertical space in the subsection headings, which messes things up. Here is a minimal LaTeX example demonstrating what you've done:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\subsection{First \vspace{0.25cm}}
\subsection{Second \vspace{-0.25cm}}
\subsection{Third }
\end{document}
```

[image]

So all you need to do is to find the subsections where you have added the vertical space, and remove it.

This is how it could appear in LyX. It may not look like the `\vspace` is part of the subsection heading, but when you place the cursor next to the vspace you'll see that it actually is. As an alternative to removing the space entirely, you could place the cursor just before the vspace, hit enter, and then set the style to *Standard*.

[image]

Comment: I used "vspace -0.25" since I noticed enough spacing between the sub section 1.1.1.2 and the chip. http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/3038863266.png

Comment: @user1936895 If you really must do that, just make sure the vspace is not part of the subsection heading.